# Firefox shows "addons updated successfully" pages everytime I restart the browser, even on Firefox 9

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I mean the pages that appears after any addon updates itself and normally is shown only once next time Firefox restart , like these

- http://screenshot-program.com/fireshot/updated.php?ver=0.95&app=fx
- http://flashgot.net/?ver=1.3.5&prev=1.3.4

but for me it is happening after each restart.(Win 7 and everything is updated )

I was waiting for Firefox 9 to remove this error that i had from 8.
but after today's update to version 9 this problem is still with me

Comment: i shift + run it in safe mode and reset every setting and controls but not yet fixed

Comment: i also upgraded to beta 10.1 today and still not fixed

Comment: Your Firefox profile is corrupt, or there is a conflict with your extensions or plugins. Try [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) to see if the problem persists.

Comment: thanks, but instead of running a clean portable version which will work i would rather go with a new profile and sync it and install my addons again. but i hoped that with some magic or resetting something it will get fixed

Comment: @iglvzx i installed portable and synced it correctly but i wish i have my normal Firefox back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I [created a new clean profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles) as @iglvzx said.

only type **firefox.exe -p** in Windows 7 and you will find out the rest.

- the nice thing is the default profile is still there in case  you want to switch back to it or to copy important files from old profile
- although i have already synced Firefox i then [Recovered important data from an old profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Recovering%20important%20data%20from%20an%20old%20profile) (like Form History, ..)
- finally i went to add-ons panel and clicked **Install Add-on from file..** command and then multiselect all my previous *.xpi files

Answer (score 2):

**@FlashGot:**

what's the value of `flashgot.firstRunRedirection` in `about:config`? If `true`, toggle it to `false`, restart Firefox and see what happens.

**@FireShot:**

Check the same with `fireshot.firstTimeRunFlag`.

Comment: thanks,these 2 was corrected. but 1 remaining problem is although extensions.foxyproxy.firstrun is false(as you said) its startup page is shown after every restart

Comment: + http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/10.0/whatsnew/ is opened after every restart + firefox checks for addons update during startup although i checked every checkbox for update option to false

Comment: even if i toggle  extensions.foxyproxy.firstrun to true and restart it will switch to false after restart as expected, but successive restart is showing firstrun page again, very weird

Comment: my startup.homepage_override_url setting is http://www.mozilla.com/%LOCALE%/%APP%/%VERSION%/whatsnew/ and i couldn't find any setting to turn this of.by the way my homepage is empty.

Comment: i removed and reinstalled the foxyproxy but the problem is not solved

Comment: checking for compatibility of addons every time i run firefox is annoying.

Comment: @"checking for compatibility of addons every time i run firefox is annoying" - this is when you run the same version a couple of times in a row? If you run alternately Fx 9, 10, 9 etc. on the same profile, then compatibility check will take place every time when the previous run was on different version.

Comment: Ad. sessions generally: I recommend you to use Session Manager: https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/session-manager/ - do you use it? It solves lots of problems with session management, restoration etc.